# Minimal polynomial (Field theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[4]{2}$.

My question is: ${\rm Polmin}(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}(i))=X^4-2$? Because: $${\rm Polmin}(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}(i)) \mid {\rm Polmin}(\alpha,\mathbb{Q})=X^4-2.$$

But $[\mathbb{Q}(i)(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(i)]=4$, so, ${\rm Polmin}(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}(i))=X^4-2$. Is this correct?

Thank you all.

Comment: How do you show that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(i)(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $4$?

Comment: I know that $[\mathbb{Q}(i)(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(i)]=4 \ (1)$, so $gr(polmin(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}(i)))=4$ is equivalently to $(1)$.

Is correct?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is a root of the $x^4-2$, the inference of your previous comment is correct.